# Calling Maxify on 3D Young Tableau?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a max 3D young tableau, so int[0][0][0] will have the largest integer in the tableau. All rows, columns, and panes are sorted in descending order. I'm trying to create the maxify method for this, but it's not working too well. I tried modifying the youngify method from [here](http://prpds.blogspot.com/2011/07/young-tablea.html) and this is what I have so far:

```
private void maxify(int i, int j, int k) {
    int largex = 0, largey = 0, largez = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    while (true) {
        x = largex;
        y = largey;
        z = largez;
        if (x + 1 > i && x + 1 < tableau.length && tableau[x + 1][y][z] > tableau[x][y][z]) {
            largex = x + 1;
            largey = y;
            largez = z;
        }
        if (y + 1 > j && y + 1 < tableau[0].length
                && tableau[x][y + 1][z] > tableau[largex][largey][largez]) {
            largex = x;
            largey = y + 1;
            largez = z;
        }
        if (z + 1 > k && z + 1 < tableau[0][0].length
                && tableau[x][y][z + 1] > tableau[largex][largey][largez]) {
            largex = x;
            largey = y;
            largez = z + 1;
        }
        if (largex != x || largey != y || largez != z) {
            tableau[x][y][z] = tableau[x][y][z] ^ tableau[largex][largey][largez];
            tableau[largex][largey][largez] = tableau[x][y][z]
                    ^ tableau[largex][largey][largez];
            tableau[x][y][z] = tableau[x][y][z] ^ tableau[largex][largey][largez];
            maxify(largex, largey, largez);
        } else
            break;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of what happens when called on a 3x3x1 array.

```
Starting with this array:
123
456
789

After first loop:    
423
156
789

And so on....    
423
156
789

423
756
189

423
756
189

423
756
819

423
756
819

423
756
891

423
756
891

423
756
891
```

The finished array:

423

756

891

is not completely sorted at all. Can anyone see what I'm missing from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original `youngify()` method doesn't actually sort a whole two-dimensional array! The problem is, after having detected a swap to be done, say on the 2nd row, the next iteration starts where the swap occurred (that is, from the 2nd row), regardless of other swaps that could be necessary on elements of the first row, but on other dimensions. In other words, it sifts down the first element first vertically then horizontally.

That's what your program output shows: the 1 travels vertically, being swapped with the 4 and the 7, then horizontally, being swapped with the 8 and the 9. In summary, the `youngify()` method correctly sifts down the top left element regardless of the rest of the array. Give the original `youngify()` method a try with the `{{9, 8, 7}, {6, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}}` array, you will see the behaviour is exactly the same.

Would repeatedly sifting down the top left element do the job? Not necessarily: if the highest element is already at the top left position, nothing will be [further] sorted at all.

What I suggest is sorting your multidimensional array “row” by “row” for each dimension. I wrote the following code:

```
private static void maxify(int[][][] tableau) {
  int ii = tableau.length;
  int jj = tableau[0].length;
  int kk = tableau[0][0].length;
  // Sort on k-rows
  for (int i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < jj; j++) {
      // Since k-rows are already standard arrays, no temporary array needed here.
      reverseSort(tableau[i][j]);
    }
  }
  // Sort on j-rows
  for (int i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < kk; k++) {
      int[] temp = new int[jj];
      for (int j = 0; j < jj; j++) {
        temp[j] = tableau[i][j][k];
      }
      reverseSort(temp);
      for (int j = 0; j < jj; j++) {
        tableau[i][j][k] = temp[j];
      }
    }
  }
  // Sort on i-rows
  for (int j = 0; j < jj; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < kk; k++) {
      int[] temp = new int[ii];
      for (int i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
        temp[i] = tableau[i][j][k];
      }
      reverseSort(temp);
      for (int i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
        tableau[i][j][k] = temp[i];
      }
    }
  }
}

private static void reverseSort(int[] a) {
  Arrays.sort(a);
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
    a[i] ^= a[a.length - i - 1];
    a[a.length - i - 1] ^= a[i];
    a[i] ^= a[a.length - i - 1];
  }
}
```

I hope this will help...

Cheers,

Jeff

Comment: Can't thank you enough, this seems to work perfectly so far!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void tableau_heapify(int r, int c) {
int[] left = this.getLeft(r, c);
int[] right = this.getRight(r, c);

int[] smallest = new int[]{r, c};

// System.out.println(r + ", " + c);
//check if the cell is less than both of its children
if (this.isCellValid(left) && this.matrix[left[0]][left[1]] < this.matrix[r][c]) {
    //save address of left cell
    smallest = left;
}

if (this.isCellValid(right) && this.matrix[right[0]][right[1]] < this.matrix[smallest[0]][smallest[1]]) {
    //save address of right cell
    smallest = right;
}

//Check if we found changed address in our smallest variables.
//If yes, swap them. And, recursively call this method on that cell address
if (this.isCellValid(smallest) && (smallest[0] != r || smallest[1] != c)) {
    //swap
    int t = this.matrix[r][c];
    this.matrix[r][c] = this.matrix[smallest[0]][smallest[1]];
    this.matrix[smallest[0]][smallest[1]] = t;

    // recursive call tableau_heapify
    this.tableau_heapify(smallest[0], smallest[1]);
}
```

}

I found here the best explanation of this cormen problem here: [Young Tableau](https://www.gyanblog.com/gyan/coding-interview/young-tableau-implementation/)